# Using osx terminal ogr2ogr to batch convert .json to .kml?

Tags: kml, ogr2ogr, batch, json, osx

using osx El Capitan terminal

This works fine one file at a time to convert .json to .kml
ogr2ogr -f "KML" xxx.kml xxx.json

I would like to do all files at once
I have tried

for %f in (*.json) do ogr2ogr -f "KML" %~.kml %f
but error is -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

I have also tried this in a .sh script

```
>#!/bin/bash                                                                                        
for FILE in *.json # cycles through all files in directory (case-sensitive!)                              
do   
    echo "converting file: $FILE..."   
    FILENEW=`echo $FILE | sed "s/.json/_new.kml/"` # replaces old filename                                   
    ogr2ogr \   
    -f "KML" \   
    $FILENEW $FILE   
done   
exit   
but gives this result
-bash: test_multi_json_convert.sh: command not found
```

Can you help?

Comment: I believe what you have comes from DOS/Windows world. In general, Mac syntax is identical to Linux, as OSX is an offshot of BSD, which forked from UNIX many years ago, but has retained much of the same syntax in things like bash.

Comment: In Linux, you would write this as: `for f in *.json; do ogr2ogr -f "KML" $f.kml $f; done` When you declare a variable, you do not precede it by a $ or %, when you reference it you do precede by a $. You need a colon before the do, and no () around *.json and a semi-colon and done to complete the loop. As for your second error, you have to make the sh file executable. `chmod +x test_multi_json_convert.sh`

Comment: Thanks John, all is ok now after begining with a fresh download of 2 new copies of the .json files, so should work with a larger number.